# Difference between the result after dividing by 2 and multiplying with 0.5

Tags: c, precision

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long int c = 9999999999999999999U / 2;
    unsigned long long int d = 9999999999999999999U * 0.5;
    unsigned long long int e = 9999999999999999999U >> 1;
    printf("%llu\n%llu\n%llu\n", c, d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

So the output of that is:

```
4999999999999999999
5000000000000000000
4999999999999999999
```

Why is there a difference when multiplied by `0.5`?
and why doesn't this difference show up when the numbers are small?

Comment: Just differences between integer division and floating point division -> integer conversion. My guess is that your floating point representation of `9999999999999999999U*0.5` can't store the whole significand so it rounds it to `1.010000...`.

Comment: try `9999999999999999999U / 2.0` and you'll see the difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `d`, `9999999999999999999` is promoted to a double, which if your C implementation uses IEEE 754 doubles, would be converted to 10000000000000000000 (if I did my calculations correctly) because they only have 53 bits available in the significand, one of which is an implied 1. Multiplying 10000000000000000000 by 0.5 is 5000000000000000000. Floating point is weird. Read up on it at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.

Comment: This is a good answer, so I would like to offer you some information on finer points. The C standard uses the term *promotions* to refer to the *integer promotions* defined in clause 6.3.1.1 of the C 2011 standard. Promotions occur even for single operands. The conversion of two arithmetic operands to a common type is the *usual arithmetic conversions*, defined in clause 6.3.1.8. The latter conversions, not integer promotion, are what cause 9999999999999999999 to be converted to `double`.

Comment: Floating-point values in the IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point format do have 53 bit significands. The significand is encoded into a 52-bit field plus information about the leading bit implied by the exponent. The 52-bit *encoding* has an implied leading bit. When we have the 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits, and 52 significand bits that represent the value, there is an implied bit for the significand. When we have the number in mathematical form, as ±1 • *f* • 2^*e*, all 53 bits are in the significand *f*. So it is not implied in this form; it is actually there. And it could be zero.

Comment: (The implied bit is zero when the exponent encoding is zero.)

Comment: yes, the closest to 9999999999999999999 in double precision is [1.0E19](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057057057057057057057057057057057057057057057057057057057) http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/

Answer (score 2):

`9999999999999999999U` is a large number. It requires 64 bits to represent in binary. Type `unsigned long long int` is guaranteed by the C Standard to have at least 64 value bits, so depending on the actual range of smaller integer types, it is a integer constant with type `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int` or at most `unsigned long long int`.

The expressions `9999999999999999999U / 2` and `9999999999999999999U >> 1` are thus fully defined and evaluate to `4999999999999999999`, typically at compile time through constant folding, with the same type. This value can be stored into `c` and `e` and output correctly by `printf` with a format `%llu` as expected.

Conversely `9999999999999999999U * 0.5` (or similarly `9999999999999999999U / 2.0`) is evaluated as a floating point expression: `(double)9999999999999999999U * 0.5`, the floating point result of type `double` is converted an `unsigned long long int` when assigned to `d`.

The `double` type is only guaranteed to provide enough precision for converting numbers up to 10 decimal digits without loss, a lot less than required for your number. Most C implementations use IEEE-754 representation for the `double` type that has exactly 53 bits of precision. The value `9999999999999999999` is thus rounded as `1E19` when converted to a `double`. Multiplying by `0.5` or dividing by `2.0` is performed exactly as it only changes the binary exponent part. The result `5E18` is converted to `unsigned long long int` and printed as `5000000000000000000` as you see on your system.

Comment: C does not guarantee at least 53 bits of precision in a `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: of course, my mistake, I reworded the answer.

Comment: The edited version of this answer is more thorough than mine and has all the relevant information I mentioned, so I upvoted it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are explained with type propagation.

First example, dividing integer by integer. Dividing by two and right-shifting are equivalent here, they are done on the operands as-is.

Second example, dividing integer by double. Here, the compiler will first convert the integer operand to a double (which only guarantees ten decimal digits, I think) and then performs the division. In order to store the result in an integer again, it is truncated.

I hope that illustrates that there are different operations going on that are caused by different types of operands, even though they seem to be the similar from a mathematical point of view.